# Tabularx, missing \cr

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to get Latex to print a table, I made in Stata.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{14cm} {@{} l Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y@{}}
toprule
    Patient died                                
    To died or exp. end No  No  No  Yes Yes Yes Total   Total   Total
    No. Col \%  Cum \%  No. Col \%  Cum \%  No. Col \%  Cum \%
    10 or less months   4   23.5    23.5    15  48.4    48.4    19  39.6    39.6
    11 to 20 months 6   35.3    58.8    8   25.8    74.2    14  29.2    68.8
    21 to 30 months 2   11.8    70.6    7   22.6    96.8    9   18.8    87.5
    31 or more months   5   29.4    100.0   1   3.2 100.0   6   12.5    100.0
    Total   17  100.0       31  100.0       48  100.0       
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\scriptsize{\emph{Source: }cancer.dta}
\normalsize
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I just can't find the mistake, I am sorry I've included almost all my code, I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't ended any of the lines of your table. You must use ``\\`` at the end of the line. (Or `\tabularnewline` but since you've issued `\arraybackslash` presumably you want to use ``\\``)

Comment: What @Au101 said. Also you'll probably want to use `&` to separate the different cells in a line. Have a look at any LaTeX introduction where tables are explained…

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It take quite of time to transform your table into `LaTeX` table ... and I'm not sure, if conversion is without errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article]{memoir}
%\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{14cm}{X *{9}{S[table-format=3.1]}}
\toprule
%    Patient died
{To died or exp. end}
                    & {No}  & {No}  & {No}  & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} &{Total}&{Total} & {Total} \\
\midrule
No. Col \%          & {\makecell{Cum\\ \%}} 
                            & {\makecell{No. Col\\ \%}} 
                                    & {\makecell{Cum\\ \%}}
                                            & {\makecell{No. Col\\ \%}} 
                                                    & {\makecell{Cum\\ \%}} 
                                                            &       &       &         &         \\ 
\midrule
10 or less months   & 4     & 23.5  & 23.5  & 15    & 48.4  & 48.4  & 19    & 39.6    & 39.6    \\
11 to 20 months 6   & 35.3  & 58.8  & 8     & 25.8  & 74.2  & 14    & 29.2  & 68.8    &         \\
21 to 30 months 2   & 11.8  & 70.6  & 7     & 22.6  & 96.8  & 9     & 18.8  & 87.5    &         \\
31 or more months   & 5     & 29.4  & 100.0 & 1     & 3.2   & 100.0 & 6     & 12.5    & 100.0   \\
Total               & 17    & 100.0 & 31    & 100.0 & 48    & 100.0 &       &         &         \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabularx}
\par
\footnotesize{\emph{Source: }cancer.dta}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I remove all packages not used in it. For nicer columns with numbers I propose to use `S` column type from package `siunitx`.